# How to customize height of scrollbar and scroll thumb?

Tags: html, css

I was wondering if there is a way to change top part starting position of scrollbar and to make custome thumb size in this case height of it,not width since its auto scale with scrollbar.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/COILj.png)

I tried using top property on scrollbar since i just wanted to change top part so i tried to move it down but it doesn't work.Actually there is a space for arrows and that is way I found to move thumb of scrollbar but it is not affecting its height.So we have two problems:TOP of scrollbar doesn't start where I want it yet it automatically gets fixed on top;Second problem is that height value of thumb cannot be adjusted .

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
   
    transform: scale(20px, 100px);
    top:30px;
}
  

  ::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    background: #0D2350;
  }
  
 
  ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background: rgb(255, 255, 255);

  }
  

  ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
    background: rgb(54, 54, 54);
  }

  ::-webkit-scrollbar-button{
    background: #0D2350;
    height: 45px;
  }
```

Comment: You can't modify the height of the scrollbar thumb; and for a good reason. The height is relative to the scale of the scrollable area and viewport height.